# Streaming live video from WCF service to Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, streaming

I need to stream live captured data (from a screen/web cam) from a WCF service to a Silverlight client. Since it's live data I don't mind losing packets... More important that it will be real-time data.
Any suggestions how can I do it?
How does the WCF service transfer it?
How does the Silverlight client should consume the stream?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check expression encoder? I haven't used it myself but it think this one of the ways to go :)